# Как правильно передать параметры Intent для установки обоев с помощью внутренних сервисов?

Tags: android, service, bitmap, android-intent, livewallpaper

Такая задача - установить обои используя внутренние сервисы такие как "Wallpaper" и "Contact Photo"(на иконку контакта).
Перепробовав многие способы, как то не складывается до конца. Проверяю на реальных устройствах, на **6 андроиде - Nexus5** устанавливается только как обои, на изображение контакта не устанавливается, на **андроиде 4.4** - никак не устанавливается, и всплывает сообщение **"Cannot load the image!"**, на других различных девайсах проверил тоже никак не устанавливается...

Логика такова:

- нажал на кнопку "Set as"
- в открывшемся диалоговом окне выбрать сервис
- если выбрали 'Contact photo' - открывается список контактов, затем выбираем контакт, затем должно появиться стандартное диалоговое окно
  с заголовком  "Complete action using", затем снова выбираем сервис
  для кропинга, и наконец жмем Done.
- если выбрали 'Wallpaper' - сразу открывается стандартный кропинг на телефоне и жмем Done.

Буду рад любой помощи!

```
Intent setAs = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA); // прикрепляю сервисы                                              
setAs.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);                                                                              
file = new File(getFolderStorageDirectory(), getFileName()); // создаю временный файл
if (isExternalStorageWritable()) { // проверяю доступна ли внешняя память                                                
    try {                                                                                                                
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);                                                               
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); // записываю изображение                                 
        out.flush();                                                                                                     
        out.close();                                                                                                     
    } catch (Exception e) {                                                                                              
        e.printStackTrace();                                                                                             
        Log.e(TAG, "File not saved");                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                    
} else {                                                                                                                 
    showToast(getString(R.string.sd_card));                                                                              
}                                                                                                                        
setAs.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");                                                      
setAs.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");                                                                                   
setAs.putExtra("jpg", "image/*");                                                                                        
setAs.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()));                                                  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(setAs, "Select service:"));
```

Почему не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел решение.

Вместо

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");
```

используйте

`setAs.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(mFile), "image/*");`

Весь код

```
private void setAsUseServices() {
        onCreateFileListener();
        Intent setAs = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
        setAs.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        Uri sourceUri = Uri.fromFile(mFile);
        setAs.setDataAndType(sourceUri, "image/*");
        setAs.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");
        setAs.putExtra("save_path", sourceUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(setAs, "Select service:"));
    }
```